# iphone setting UITextView delegate breaks auto completion

Tags: iphone, autocomplete, delegates, uitextview, uitextviewdelegate

I have a UITextField that I would like to enable auto completion on by:

```
[self.textView setAutocorrectionType:UITextAutocorrectionTypeYes];
```

This works normally, except when I give the UITextView a delegate. When a delegate is set, auto complete just stops working. The delegate has only the following method:

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
 self.textView.text = [self.textView.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];

 int left = LENGTH_MAX -[self.textView.text length];
 self.characterCountLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",abs(left)];

}
```

Does anyone know how to have both auto complete enabled and a delegate set?

Thanks!
Tristan

Comment: Would it be ok for you to elaborate on why you need to strip out \n characters?

Comment: Hi Jasarien. The textView is taking messages from the user to be published in a twitter-like manner. They are supposed to be no more than a few sentences and all on a single line. I suppose I could simply remove the new lines after the user has submitted the message, but this isn't ideal. I would expect there to be a way to use standard delegate methods without breaking other functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSRange r= [self.textView.text rangeOfString:@"\n"];
if(r.location!=NSNotFound) //must check before replacing new lines right away, otherwise spellcheck gets broken
{
    self.textView.text = [self.textView.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
}
```

The problem was caused by doing something that potentially modifies the text every time it was changed (ie calling replace method). The solution was to only call the replace method when it was necessary.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably breaking autocompletion because you're simultaneously modifying the text in the `UITextView`.

Answer (score 0):

Get this: All you need to do is remove UITextViewDelegate from your interface (.h) file.

You can still set the delegate to the textView in the nib.

Odd, right? Worked for me, I hope it would solve your problem as well.